# Use put two value columns in spread() function in R

Tags: r, reshape2, tidyr

I just posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063959/reshape-data-in-r-change-a-long-table-into-a-wide-table/31064417?noredirect=1#comment50242156_31064417) recently asking how to reshape data from a long table to a wide table. Then I found `spread()` is a quite handy function for doing this. So now I need some further development on my previous post.

Let's suppose we have a table like this:

```
id1   |  id2 |  info  | action_time | action_comment  |
 1    | a    |  info1 |    time1    |        comment1 |
 1    | a    |  info1 |    time2    |        comment2 |
 1    | a    |  info1 |    time3    |        comment3 |
 2    | b    |  info2 |    time4    |        comment4 |
 2    | b    |  info2 |    time5    |        comment5 |
```

And I would like to change it to something like this:

```
id1   |  id2 |  info  |action_time 1|action_comment1 |action_time 2|action_comment2 |action_time 3|action_comment3  |
 1    | a    |  info1 |    time1    |      comment1  |    time2    |      comment2  |    time3    |      comment3   |
 2    | b    |  info2 |    time4    |      comment4  |    time5    |      comment5  |             |                 |
```

So the difference between this question and my previous question is I added another column and I need it to be reshaped as well.

I'm thinking to use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id1) %>% 
  mutate(action_no = paste("action_time", row_number())) %>%
  spread(action_no, value = c(action_time, action_comment))
```

But it gives me an error message when I put two values in `value` argument saying : **Invalid column specification.**

I really like the idea of using such `%>%` operator to manipulate data, so I'm keen to know how to correct my code to make this happen.

Much appreciate for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id1) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, -(id1:info), -id) %>%
  unite(id_key, id, key) %>%
  spread(id_key, value)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [2 x 9]

#  id1 id2  info 1_action_comment 1_action_time 2_action_comment 2_action_time 3_action_comment 3_action_time
#1   1   a info1         comment1         time1         comment2         time2         comment3         time3
#2   2   b info2         comment4         time4         comment5         time5               NA            NA
```

Comment: do you think there is a way to put `action_comment1` and `action_time1` side by side so it makes me easier to compare. Otherwise I can still go with this format. Thanks

Comment: @Lambo Would you mind having the columns named 1_action_comment ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I may change the header anyway

Comment: I got an error running the above code: `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names`

Comment: @user2540309 Try with akrun's dataset it should work

Answer (score 8):

We could do this with the devel version of `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var` columns.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), create a sequence variable ('ind') using the grouping variables ('id1', 'id2', 'info'), and `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide' format by specifying the `value.var` as 'action_time' and 'action_comment'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df)[, ind:= 1:.N, .(id1, id2, info)]
dcast(df, id1 + id2 + info ~ ind,
      value.var=c('action_time', 'action_comment'), fill='')
 #    id1 id2  info 1_action_time 2_action_time 3_action_time 1_action_comment
 #1:   1   a info1         time1         time2         time3         comment1
 #2:   2   b info2         time4         time5                       comment4
 #   2_action_comment 3_action_comment
 #1:         comment2         comment3
 #2:         comment5
```

Or use `reshape` from `base R`.  We create the sequence variable ('ind') with `ave` and `reshape` to change from 'long' to 'wide' format.

```
df$ind <- with(df, ave(seq_along(id1), id1, id2, info, FUN=seq_along))
reshape(df, idvar=c('id1', 'id2', 'info'),timevar='ind', direction='wide')
#  id1 id2  info action_time.1 action_comment.1 action_time.2 action_comment.2
#1   1   a info1         time1         comment1         time2         comment2
#4   2   b info2         time4         comment4         time5         comment5
#  action_time.3 action_comment.3
#1         time3         comment3
#4          <NA>             <NA>
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), id2 = c("a", "a", 
"a", "b", "b"), info = c("info1", "info1", "info1", "info2", 
"info2"), action_time = c("time1", "time2", "time3", "time4", 
"time5"), action_comment = c("comment1", "comment2", "comment3", 
"comment4", "comment5")), .Names = c("id1", "id2", "info", "action_time", 
"action_comment"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: would you mind explaining the: `with(df, ave(seq_along(id1), id1, id2, info, FUN=seq_along))`. Why does `seq_along` appear twice?

Comment: @user2540309  It is not needed here, but if there are character/factor columns, `ave` output could be 'character' vector/NA.  For e.g. `v1 <- rep(letters[1:3],3); ave(v1, v1, FUN=seq_along); v2 <- factor(v1);ave(v2, v2, FUN=seq_along)`  In both cases, using `seq_along` would give the numeric sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Not a straight forward solution, but works

```
library(tidyr)
a = spread(df, action_comment, action_time); 
b = spread(df, action_time, action_comment); 

# dropping NAs and shifting the values to left row wise 
a[] = t(apply(a, 1, function(x) `length<-`(na.omit(x), length(x))))
b[] = t(apply(b, 1, function(x) `length<-`(na.omit(x), length(x))))

out = merge(a,b, by = c('id1','id2','info'))
out[, colSums(is.na(out)) != nrow(out)]

#  id1 id2  info comment1 comment2 comment3    time1    time2    time3
#1   1   a info1    time1    time2    time3 comment1 comment2 comment3
#2   2   b info2    time4    time5     <NA> comment4 comment5     <NA>
```