# Reshape/Transpose select columns of a data.frame in R

Tags: r, transform, reshape, transpose

I'm doing some data analysis in R, and I have the following data in a data.frame:

```
  v1 v2
1 11  3
2 11  4
3 11  5
4 15  6
5 15  7
6 20  8
```

And I would like to transform it into the following:

```
 col1   col2 col3 col4
 11     3    4    5
 15     6    7    Null
 20     8    Null Null
```

I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone has any suggestions.  I can do it in a for loop, but I'm wondering if there is a built-in function in R.

Thanks.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322801/transpose-reshape-dataframe-without-timevar-from-long-to-wide-format) a similar post

Answer (score 0):

You can try a combination of `split`, `do.call`, `lapply` `dcast` (from `reshape2`) and `rbind.fill` (from `plyr`) to get your desired output:

#### Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 15L, 15L, 20L), v2 = 3:8), .Names = c("v1", 
"v2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

#### Code:

```
do.call(plyr::rbind.fill,lapply(split(df1, df1$v1), function(x) {
    tempdf <- data.frame(reshape2::dcast(x, v1~v2, value.var = "v2"))
    names(tempdf) <- paste("col", 1:ncol(tempdf), sep = "")
    return(tempdf)
}))
```

#### Output:

```
 col1 col2 col3 col4
 11   3     4    5  
 15   6     7   NA  
 20   8    NA   NA
```

#### Explanation:

The idea here to `split` your data.frame by the column `v1`; and for each of the subsets you apply a `dcast` operation with the formula `v1 ~ v2`. This means to arrange all values in column `v2` into one row, prepended by the value in `v1`. Once you are done `cast`ing the subsets, you can then join the results together using `rbind.fill` from the `plyr` package.

I hope this helps.