# How to lapply grep() data by id

Tags: r, lapply

I have a df `RawDat` with two rows `ID, data`. I want to grep() my data by the id using e.g. lapply() to generate a new df where the data is sorted into columns by their id:
My df looks like this, except I have >80000 rows, and 75 ids:

`ID     data
abl     564
dlh     78
vho     354
mez     15
abl     662
dlh     69
vho     333
mez     9
.
.
.`

I can manually extract the data using the grep() function:

```
ExtRawDat = as.data.frame(RawDat[grep("abl",RawDat$ID),])
```

However, I would not want to do that 75 times and cbind() them. Rather, I would like to use the lapply() function to automate it. I have tried several variations of the following code, but I don't get a script that provide the desired output.

I have a vector with the 75 ids `ProLisV`, to loop my argument

```
ExtRawDat = as.data.frame(lapply(ProLisV[1:75],function(x){     
Temp1 = RawDat[grep(x,RawDat$ID),]      # The issue is here, the pattern is not properly defined with the X input (is it detrimental that some of the names in the list having spaces etc.?)
Values = as.data.frame(Temp1$data)
list(Values$data)
}))
```

The desired output looks like this:

`abl     dlh    vho     mez     ...
 564     78     354     15
 662     69     333     9
 .
 .
 .`

How do I adjust that function to provide the desired output? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you are trying to do is to convert your data from long form to wide form. One way to do this easily is to use the `spread` function from the `tidyr` package. To use it, we need a column to [remove duplicate identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898614/how-to-spread-columns-with-duplicate-identifiers?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), so we'll first add a grouping variable:

```
n.ids <- 4 # With your full data this should be 75
df$group <- rep(1:n.ids, each = n.ids, length.out = nrow(df))
tidyr::spread(df, ID, data)

#   group abl dlh mez vho
# 1     1 564  78  15 354
# 2     2 662  69   9 333
```

If you don't want the `group` column at the end, just do `df$group <- NULL`.

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
  ID     data
  abl     564
  dlh     78
  vho     354
  mez     15
  abl     662
  dlh     69
  vho     333
  mez     9", header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you C. Braun! That is a very succinct solution to exactly what I was trying to do. One thing though: After 75 groups, the groups begin from 1 again, and the tidyr::spread() throws an error due to `Duplicate identifiers for rows` How do I tell the rep() function to keep numbering up until the end of rows? Thank you.

Comment: In the rep() function the first argument should read `1:nrow(RawDat)`