# I would like to convert my data from long to wide format but I get each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys

Tags: r, tidyr

I have this data with **two variables**, and I would like to convert the **Atc-codes** in wide format, creating multiple rows per patient (`Pseudo_ID`).

The code that I am using is below, but I get this error

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfB0C.png): Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of
> keys. Keys are shared for 594871 rows

```
library(tidyr)

Meds18_wide <- spread(MEDS18, key = Pseudo_ID, value = Atc_code)
```

Comment: This already has a very detailed explanation [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45898919/1335174). Essentially, you need to help `spread` (which btw is now superseded by `pivot_wider`) by creating at least one other column in your df that (together with "Pseudo_ID" uniquely identifies each row

Comment: Thanks I already worked it out :)