# Azure Machine Learning execute R script - Could not find function "rowid" error

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to run R script in **Azure ML studio** that transposes/reshapes the dataframe from long to wide format ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322801/transpose-reshape-dataframe-without-timevar-from-long-to-wide-format)). My script runs very fine in Rstudio. But the same does not run in Azure ML studio and throws the following error - could not find function "rowid". It would be great to know how can I get rid of this and what exactly is causing this error despite it being good enough to run neatly in Rstudio.

```
#Error: Error 0063: The following error occurred during evaluation of R script:
# ---------- Start of error message from R ----------
      could not find function "rowid"
# ----------- End of error message from R -----------
```

I've tried the code in both R versions *CRAN R 3.1.0* & *Microsoft R open 3.2.2*.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Seems to be fairly straightforward - are you sure data.table is installed in your Azure virtual environment?

Comment: Yes! Here is the list of all packages installed(or supported) by Azure environment - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt741980.aspx

Comment: Maybe try specifying your function call like `data.table::rowid()`?

Comment: Well hold on, those are supported packages yes, but did you import them in your script? I see it commented out in your question but you do need to import them explicitly.

Comment: If I execute `data.table::rowid()` - I get error -  'rowid' is not an exported object from 'namespace:data.table' ; 
Also, I've put hashtag to let people know that I've already imported these libraries in Azure ML environment.

Comment: Maybe your version of data.table is too old to have rowid. You can check the package NEWS to see when it was added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I had the same problem 2 days ago with the function `pull()`, always of the package `dplyr`.
The problem is that the both version of R (CRAN R 3.1.0 and Microsoft R open 3.2.2) supported by Azure Machine Learning Studio, does not support the version `0.7.4` of package `dplyr`.
If you read the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf) related to the package `dplyr` you can see that the package is installable only for R versions >= 3.1.2.

Then you must wait for the R version used by Azure Machine Learning Studio be updated, or find an alternative solution to your function.