# Convert data frame into a matrix of "ranked lists" based on unique values in column

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, ranking

Let's say I have a data frame `df` that looks like this:

```
df = data.frame(c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E"), 
        c(0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.8, 0.4, 0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1),
        c("v1", "v2", "v1", "v3", "v4", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v2"))

colnames(df) = c("entry", "value", "point")
df = df[order(df$entry, -df$value),]

df
   entry value point
2     A   0.3    v2
1     A   0.1    v1
4     B   0.8    v3
3     B   0.1    v1
5     C   0.4    v4
6     D   0.7    v2
7     D   0.5    v3
8     D   0.2    v4
9     E   0.1    v2
```

I would like to convert it eventually into a matrix of "ranked lists", that has as rows the unique values in the `entry` column and the number of columns should be equal to the **maximum** number of unique elements in the `point` column for a given `entry`. In this example it would be 3. Each row should be populated with the corresponding values from the `point` column, sorted descendingly based on the corresponding elements in `value` (e.g., row `A` should have `v2` as value in the first column). In case an `entry` has less `points` than the number of columns in the matrix, the rest of the row should be filled with `NAs`.

So, the expected output should look something like this:

```
>df
   1   2   3  
A  v2  v1  NA 
B  v3  v1  NA 
C  v4  NA  NA 
D  v2  v3  v4
E  v2  NA  NA
```

So far I have tried to create some sort of contingency table using

```
with(df, table(df$point, df$entry))
```

but of course my actual data is in the order of millions of entries, and the above command raises to huge amounts of RAM even when subsetting to 100 `entries` with a couple hundreds of unique `points`. I have also tried

```
xtabs(~ entry + point, data=df)
```

with the same results on my real data. Next I have tried to split it into ordered lists using

```
df = split(df$point, df$entry)
```

which works fine and it is fast enough, buuuuut.. now I have problems converting it to the result matrix. Something along those lines probably

```
matrix(sapply(df, function(x) unlist(x)), nrow=length(df), ncol=max(sapply(df, length)))
```

or first initialize a matrix and do some `rbind` or something?

```
res = matrix(NA, nrow=length(df), ncol=max(sapply(df, length)))
rownames(res) = names(df)
....
```

Can you please assist?

Comment: Seems like this may do it: [Transpose / reshape dataframe without “timevar” from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322801/transpose-reshape-dataframe-without-timevar-from-long-to-wide-format), e.g. `dcast(df, entry ~ rowid(entry), value.var = "point")`

Comment: @Henrik It's along those lines, but the problem with `reshape` is that it keeps as columns all the unique `value`s and not the maximum number of elements for a given `entry`. Plus, they are not sorted. If you look at the expected output, maybe it is clearer

Comment: At least for the example provided in the post, my suggestion gives the desired output. And sorry, I forgot `library(data.table)`, `setDT(df)` before the `dcast`.

Comment: @Henrik: it doesn't really. it produces (only first line as example):
     `entry point.0.3 point.0.1 point.0.8 point.0.4 point.0.7 point.0.5 point.0.2`
    `2     A        v2        v1      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>`
It should be only `A   v2  v1  NA` .. not 7 columns, but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Forgot to mention (again..;): I started with your sorted data. (if you use `setDT` and `dcast`, you can just as well sort it with `setorder(df, entry, -value)`).

Comment: @Henrik Yes, like that indeed it generates the desired output :] You can still set it as an answer if you will or modify the comment accordingly. Thank you for the help!

Comment: No, I prefer not to reiterate answers already provided elsewhere.

Comment: @Henrik: well, you should. It proved to be the most stable and the fastest solution among all the suggested ones. I would accept it as **the** answer. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(entry) %>% 
   mutate(unq=rank(rev(value))) %>% 
   select(-value) %>% 
   tidyr::spread(unq,point)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   entry [5]
  entry `1`   `2`   `3`  
  <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
1 A     v2    v1    NA   
2 B     v3    v1    NA   
3 C     v4    NA    NA   
4 D     v2    v3    v4   
5 E     v2    NA    NA
```

Comment: Perfect :] Can you please add also that it requires the `tidyr` package for the `spread` function. Thanks a bunch for the help

Comment: yeah, forgot about it

Comment: Just a heads up: in case of millions of entries in your data frame you might very well get a `Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows` from the `tidyr::spread` function which will eventually force you to assign new row IDs via `tibble::rowid_to_column()` as the second line in the above command.. issue is known but not fixed

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `by` to split by *entry* and build needed vectors. For same length rows in final matrix, add `NA` as needed where the below `3` can be changed to however many columns required.

```
vec_list <- by(df, df$entry, function(sub) {
    vec <- as.character(sub[order(-sub$value),]$point)    
    c(vec, rep(NA, 3 - length(vec)))    
})

final_matrix <- do.call(rbind, vec_list)

final_matrix
#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
# A "v2" "v1" NA  
# B "v3" "v1" NA  
# C "v4" NA   NA  
# D "v2" "v3" "v4"
# E "v2" NA   NA
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/GJH16784)

Comment: Yeah, this works too. Maybe to avoid the hardcoded `3` it can be passed as a parameter via `max(table(df$entry))` or something along those lines. Thanks for this `r base` solution!