# R how to 'spread' data with no key-value pair

Tags: r, tidyr

I have data:

```
rowID    incidentID participant.type
1          1                A
2          1                B
3          2                A
4          3                A
5          3                B
6          3                C
7          4                B
8          4                C
```

And I would like to end up with:

```
   rowID incident participant.type participant.type.1 participant.type.2
    1        1                A                  B                   
    2        2                A                                      
    3        3                A                  B                  C
    4        4                B                  C
```

I tried the spread but can't achieve one line per incident; I don't think I have a way of creating a key-value pair so I wonder if there is some other method for doing this.

Comment: The fourth row should be `A`, not `B C`.

Comment: yes thanks, corrected

Comment: Related [Transpose / reshape dataframe without “timevar” from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322801/transpose-reshape-dataframe-without-timevar-from-long-to-wide-format)

Comment: That link provides several solutions and I have added one of them as an answer below, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using `spread()`, you need to create a proper `key` argument.

```
df %>% select(-rowID) %>%
       group_by(incidentID) %>%
       mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
       spread(id, participant.type)

#   incidentID  `1`   `2`   `3`  
#        <int>  <fct> <fct> <fct>
# 1          1  A     B     NA   
# 2          2  A     NA    NA   
# 3          3  A     B     C    
# 4          4  B     C     NA
```

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since your grouping is based on the row order within the icidentID column. The following simple solution will also work.

It is just filtering the dataframe and then merging in the end.

It is probably not the best solution in terms of effective use of computing power, but it is easy to understand.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
  tribble(
    ~rowID,    ~incidentID, ~participant.type,
    1,          1,                "A",
    2,          1,                "B",
    3,          2,                "A",
    4,          3,                "A",
    5,          3,                "B",
    6,          3,                "C",
    7,          4,                "B",
    8,          4,                "C")

df_1 <- df %>%
  select(-rowID) %>% 
  group_by(incidentID) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==1)


df_2 <- df %>%
  select(-rowID) %>% 
  group_by(incidentID) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==2) %>% 
  rename(participant.type.1 = participant.type)


df_3 <- df %>%
  select(-rowID) %>% 
  group_by(incidentID) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==3) %>% 
  rename(participant.type.2 = participant.type) 

full_join(df_1, full_join(df_2, df_3))
```

Result:

```
Joining, by = "incidentID"
Joining, by = "incidentID"
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   incidentID [?]
  incidentID participant.type participant.type.1 participant.type.2
       <dbl> <chr>            <chr>              <chr>             
1          1 A                B                  NA                
2          2 A                NA                 NA                
3          3 A                B                  C                 
4          4 B                C                  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
df %>%
  select(-rowID) %>%
  group_by(incidentID) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = map_chr(data, ~str_c(.x$participant.type, collapse = '_'))) %>%
  separate(data, paste0('participant.type.', 0:2)) %>%
  mutate_at(2:4, ~replace_na(.x, ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `reshape2::dcast` for this

```
reshape2::dcast(df, insidentID ~ participant.type)    
  #   insidentID    A    B    C
  # 1          1 <NA>    B <NA>
  # 2          8 <NA>    B <NA>
  # 3         12 <NA> <NA>    C
  # 4         16    A <NA> <NA>
  # 5         24 <NA>    B <NA>
  # 6         27 <NA>    B    C
  # 7         29 <NA> <NA>    C
```

with the data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(insidentID = sample(0:30, 8L, replace = TRUE),
                 participant.type = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 8L, replace = TRUE),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#   insidentID participant.type
# 1          8                B
# 2         24                B
# 3         12                C
# 4         27                B
# 5         29                C
# 6          1                B
# 7         16                A
# 8         27                C
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'related question' link provided by @markus shows a variety of other solutions, including what appears to be the most concise in a tidyverse format:

```
 df %>% 
  group_by(incidentID) %>%
  mutate(rn = paste0("newcolumn",row_number()))  %>%
  spread(rn, participant.type)
```

gives:

```
incidentID newcolumn1 newcolumn2 newcolumn3
       <int> <fct>      <fct>      <fct>     
1          1 A          B          NA        
2          2 A          NA         NA        
3          3 A          B          C         
4          4 B          C          NA
```

A

Comment: If you don't remove the variable `rowID`, the output won't be what you show above. And your solution is equivalent to mine. You don't need to post it again.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I think I posted the code based on the link before I saw yours. I've marked yours as the solution.