# Multiple column spread

Tags: r, reshape, tidyverse, spread

I have a need to do what is really what `tidyr::spread()` does, but for multiple value columns.

If I have a data set like this:

```
te <- structure(list(Syllable = c("[pa]", "[ta]", "[ka]", "[pa]", "[ta]", 
"[ka]", "[pa]", "[ta]", "[ka]", "[pa]"), PA = c(15.9252335141423, 
2.17504491982172, 5.26727958979289, 4.48590068583509, 2.1316282072803e-13, 
14.1415335887116, 3.51720477328246, 0.839953301362556, 5.74712643678048, 
7.01396701583887), transient_mean = c(4.43699436235785, 4.8733556527069, 
5.52844792982797, 3.63255704032305, 4.99835680315547, 5.5387775503751, 
3.19517346916471, 4.40360523945946, 4.14203491258186, 3.51900453101706
), transient_sd = c(0.871280094068596, 1.51392328075964, 2.65764846931951, 
1.25416942799974, 1.13391173514884, 1.75904804912773, 1.54594113209317, 
1.69526308849507, 1.73693971862859, 1.31626295142865)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

which looks like this (for those of you just reading this):

```
> te
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   Syllable       PA transient_mean transient_sd
   <chr>       <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 [pa]     1.59e+ 1           4.44        0.871
 2 [ta]     2.18e+ 0           4.87        1.51 
 3 [ka]     5.27e+ 0           5.53        2.66 
 4 [pa]     4.49e+ 0           3.63        1.25 
 5 [ta]     2.13e-13           5.00        1.13 
 6 [ka]     1.41e+ 1           5.54        1.76 
 7 [pa]     3.52e+ 0           3.20        1.55 
 8 [ta]     8.40e- 1           4.40        1.70 
 9 [ka]     5.75e+ 0           4.14        1.74 
10 [pa]     7.01e+ 0           3.52        1.32
```

I would like to make new columns from the value of the `Syllable` column values so that I get a wider tibble with column names "[pa]*PA","[pa]* transient_mean","[pa]_ transient_sd",[ta]_PA","[ta]_transient_mean", .... and so on.

I have tried this of course:

```
> te %>%
+   spread(Syllable,PA:transient_sd)
Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not an integer vector
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

but I get a complaint then, presumably due to me selecting multiple columns.

Any ideas on how this data wrangling can be achieved?

Comment: Seems relevant: [Transpose / reshape dataframe without “timevar” from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322801/transpose-reshape-dataframe-without-timevar-from-long-to-wide-format)

Answer (score 1):

Probably your data is lacking a time variable that counts different observations of `"[pa]", "[ta]", "[ka]"`. You could fix this with `ave`.

```
te$time <- with(te, ave(as.character(Syllable), Syllable, FUN=seq_along))
te
# # A tibble: 10 x 5
#    Syllable       PA transient_mean transient_sd time 
#    <chr>       <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>
#  1 [pa]     1.59e+ 1           4.44        0.871 1    
#  2 [ta]     2.18e+ 0           4.87        1.51  1    
#  3 [ka]     5.27e+ 0           5.53        2.66  1    
#  4 [pa]     4.49e+ 0           3.63        1.25  2    
#  5 [ta]     2.13e-13           5.00        1.13  2    
#  6 [ka]     1.41e+ 1           5.54        1.76  2    
#  7 [pa]     3.52e+ 0           3.20        1.55  3    
#  8 [ta]     8.40e- 1           4.40        1.70  3    
#  9 [ka]     5.75e+ 0           4.14        1.74  3    
# 10 [pa]     7.01e+ 0           3.52        1.32  4
```

After that you could use `reshape` of base R.

```
reshape(as.data.frame(te), timevar="Syllable", idvar="time", direction="wide")
#    time   PA.[pa] transient_mean.[pa] transient_sd.[pa]      PA.[ta]
# 1     1 15.925234            4.436994         0.8712801 2.175045e+00
# 4     2  4.485901            3.632557         1.2541694 2.131628e-13
# 7     3  3.517205            3.195173         1.5459411 8.399533e-01
# 10    4  7.013967            3.519005         1.3162630           NA
#    transient_mean.[ta] transient_sd.[ta]   PA.[ka] transient_mean.[ka]
# 1             4.873356          1.513923  5.267280            5.528448
# 4             4.998357          1.133912 14.141534            5.538778
# 7             4.403605          1.695263  5.747126            4.142035
# 10                  NA                NA        NA                  NA
#    transient_sd.[ka]
# 1           2.657648
# 4           1.759048
# 7           1.736940
# 10                NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(te,k,val,-Syllable) %>% mutate(k=paste0(Syllable,'_',k)) %>% 
select(-Syllable) %>% group_by(k) %>% mutate(rid=row_number()) %>% 
spread(k,val) %>% select(-rid)

# A tibble: 4 x 9
    `[ka]_PA` `[ka]_transient_~ `[ka]_transient_~ `[pa]_PA` `[pa]_transient~ `[pa]_transient~ `[ta]_PA` `[ta]_transient~ `[ta]_transient~
      <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>     <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>     <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1     5.27              5.53              2.66     15.9              4.44            0.871  2.18e+ 0             4.87             1.51
2     14.1               5.54              1.76      4.49             3.63            1.25   2.13e-13             5.00             1.13
3     5.75              4.14              1.74      3.52             3.20            1.55   8.40e- 1             4.40             1.70
4     NA                NA                NA         7.01             3.52            1.32  NA                   NA               NA
```