# Selecting group and value sets when using pivot_longer for reshaping

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse, tidyr

As noted in 
[Reshaping multiple sets of measurement columns (wide format) into single columns (long format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns) and
[Elegant solution for casting (spreading) multiple columns of character vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57374484/elegant-solution-for-casting-spreading-multiple-columns-of-character-vectors/57378299#57378299),
you can use the `".value"` component of the names_to argument in tidyr's *pivot_wider()* to make multiple columns longer at once:

```
tibble(
  name = LETTERS[1:10],
  a_x = 1:10,
  a_y = -1:-10,
  b_x = 1:10,
  b_y = -1:-10,
  c_x = 1:10,
  c_y = -1:-10,
  d_x = 1:10,
  d_y = -1:-10
) %>% 
 pivot_longer(
  cols = -name,
  names_to = c(".value", "group"),
  names_sep = "_",

)
```

which produces this:

```
# A tibble: 20 x 6
   name  group     a     b     c     d
   <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 A     x         1     1     1     1
 2 A     y        -1    -1    -1    -1
 3 B     x         2     2     2     2
 4 B     y        -2    -2    -2    -2
 5 C     x         3     3     3     3
 6 C     y        -3    -3    -3    -3
 7 D     x         4     4     4     4
 8 D     y        -4    -4    -4    -4
 9 E     x         5     5     5     5
10 E     y        -5    -5    -5    -5
11 F     x         6     6     6     6
12 F     y        -6    -6    -6    -6
13 G     x         7     7     7     7
14 G     y        -7    -7    -7    -7
15 H     x         8     8     8     8
16 H     y        -8    -8    -8    -8
17 I     x         9     9     9     9
18 I     y        -9    -9    -9    -9
19 J     x        10    10    10    10
20 J     y       -10   -10   -10   -10
```

This is useful, but it presumes that the *suffix* provides the grouping component on which to pivot.  However, sometimes one might want to pivot on the prefix, for instance where *abcd* would go in the group column and *xy* would be the two columns.

This was apparently talked about in the original discussion around this feature [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/586) but if there's a solution to implement it I can't seem to make any headway.

I can do this other ways, for instance with base reshape() and *varying*, or with creating a pivoting specification, but can this be done cleanly with this tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of `".value"` in the `names_to` vector determines which component is used as the new column names. To get *xy* as the new columns, you would use `names_to = c("group", ".value")`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  name = LETTERS[1:10],
  a_x = 1:10,
  a_y = -1:-10,
  b_x = 1:10,
  b_y = -1:-10,
  c_x = 1:10,
  c_y = -1:-10,
  d_x = 1:10,
  d_y = -1:-10
) %>% 
 pivot_longer(
  cols = -name,
  names_to = c("group", ".value"),
  names_sep = "_",
)
#> # A tibble: 40 x 4
#>    name  group     x     y
#>    <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
#>  1 A     a         1    -1
#>  2 A     b         1    -1
#>  3 A     c         1    -1
#>  4 A     d         1    -1
#>  5 B     a         2    -2
#>  6 B     b         2    -2
#>  7 B     c         2    -2
#>  8 B     d         2    -2
#>  9 C     a         3    -3
#> 10 C     b         3    -3
#> # ... with 30 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9000)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but that's distinctly not the outcome I was getting from doing just that.  Let me check my versions and try it again.

Comment: I ran my example with the latest GitHub master branch. If you're not getting the same result, I'd recommend opening an issue.

Comment: Belated follow up to say that although I didn't get to re-check this at the time, I've since used it effectively, so whatever I was seeing seems to have resolved either in an update or when I somehow corrected my misunderstanding.