# How do I transform a data frame to the desired structure and form?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, pivot, extract

My data is a `.xlsx` pivot table. There are several sheets there, but I need only one for my analysis. On this sheet I have a data frame which looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(ind = c("ind1", "ind1", "ind1", "ind1", 
                         "ind2", "ind2", "ind2", "ind2",
                         "ind3", "ind3", "ind3", "ind3",
                         "ind4", "ind4", "ind4", "ind4"),
                 shr = c(-0.23, 0, 0.12, 0.68,
                         -0.54, 0.80, 0.14, -0.23,
                          0.48, 0.94, -0.01, 0.31,
                          0.18, 0.11, 0.98, 0.05))
```

And other columns with different types of data. I don't need them, only these two I have presented in an example. So, the df is:

```
df
#    ind   shr
#1  ind1 -0.23
#2  ind1  0.00
#3  ind1  0.12
#4  ind1  0.68
#5  ind2 -0.54
#6  ind2  0.80
#7  ind2  0.14
#8  ind2 -0.23
#9  ind3  0.48
#10 ind3  0.94
#11 ind3 -0.01
#12 ind3  0.31
#13 ind4  0.18
#14 ind4  0.11
#15 ind4  0.98
#16 ind4  0.05
```

What I need is to transform this dataframe to this form:

```
df
#      shr
# ind1 -0.23 0.00 0.12 0.68
# ind2 -0.54 0.80 0.14 -0.23
# ind3 .....
# ind4 .....
```

Or even it would be also convenient if my data have looked like this:

```
df
# ind1   ind2   ind3   ind4
# -0.23   .      .
#  0.00   .      .
#  0.12   .      .
#  0.68   .      .
```

In short, I want to make my data compact and comfortable for further analysis. The main difficulties are that my initial file with data is the `.xlsx` with different sheets and pivot table.

(1) How do I extract data from `.xlsx` file with several sheets?
(2) How can I get desirable df structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322801/transpose-reshape-dataframe-without-timevar-from-long-to-wide-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to tranform your data. `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` requires an ID column. Here I create one using `mutate(row = row_number())`. To read the data from excel, I suggest the `readxl` package. The `read_xlsx` function allows you to specify the excel sheet and the range.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ind) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from= ind, values_from = shr) %>%
  select(-row)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
   ind1  ind2  ind3  ind4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 -0.23 -0.54  0.48  0.18
2  0     0.8   0.94  0.11
3  0.12  0.14 -0.01  0.98
4  0.68 -0.23  0.31  0.05
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code:

```
list1<-c(1:4)
df$col<-1:nrow(df)
df$remainder<-df$col%%4
df$col<-NULL

dcast(df,ind~remainder, value.var = "shr" )

>   ind     0     1    2     3
1 ind1  0.68 -0.23 0.00  0.12
2 ind2 -0.23 -0.54 0.80  0.14
3 ind3  0.31  0.48 0.94 -0.01
4 ind4  0.05  0.18 0.11  0.98

dcast(df,remainder~ind, value.var = "shr" )

>  remainder  ind1  ind2  ind3 ind4
1         0  0.68 -0.23  0.31 0.05
2         1 -0.23 -0.54  0.48 0.18
3         2  0.00  0.80  0.94 0.11
4         3  0.12  0.14 -0.01 0.98
```

Comment: `dcast(setDT(df), ind~rowid(ind), value.var = 'shr')`