# Can we break values in rows to columns in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset in below format

[image]

I am trying to get an output in below format using R. The product names for each sales order must be split in columns. There are multiple SalesOrderNumbers and for each of the the numbers of products could be n.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322801/transpose-reshape-dataframe-without-timevar-from-long-to-wide-format to be specific.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a "convert data frame from long to wide format" question. There are many resources on that. The post "[How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)" will give you directions on how to do it. Here is another source https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/long-wide-data-R.

**Please** try that, first. If you have any trouble with it, we will be glad to help you.