# could not transpose excel file with 1 row in dataframe r shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, shiny-server

I have an excel file with 2 columns (1st column with headers & 2nd with data) and I'm trying it to transpose it(1st row with headers & 2nd with data). For some reason my code is only working for the data with >= 2rows.

```
  Input Excel:
```

[image]

```
    Expected Output:
```

[image]

```
    Code:
    df <- df_customer_upload()                     # original excel file
    df <- t(df_customer_upload())                  # Transposed excel file, in matrix format
    colnames(df) <- (df[1, ])                      # Copies 1st row to the header
    df <- df[-1,]                            # after copying 1st row as header, deletes the 1st row
    View(df)
```

Output I got:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try these solutions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322801/transpose-reshape-dataframe-without-timevar-from-long-to-wide-format and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Comment: Try `df <- df[-1, , drop = FALSE]`. In the case of two rows the matrix is by default simplified to a vector when dropping one row (or column). To prevent this add argument drop=FALSE.

Comment: Hi @stefan, If I place drop =FALSE, it is creating an empty row with NA's which I don't want. Any idea about it?

Comment: @RoshmithaReddy Unfortunately no. But I don't think that this is related to drop=FALSE as it only prevents the conversion to a vector.