# Convert Tibble to Matrix in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

## tibble

[image]

How can I convert above tibble into following output matrix?

(how I can  split **PT then Pessary** put the value 172 in to the position (2,1) and also for the rest value?)

(Note Pessary then Pessary = 809 can be added to Pessary = 6238, In ouput it should be 6238+809 not 6238, same for all others)

## output Image

[image]

Comment: Post your data as text, make it reproducible `dput(mydata)`.

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Try the solutions from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322801/transpose-reshape-dataframe-without-timevar-from-long-to-wide-format

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option

```
xtabs(
    n ~ .,
    setDT(df)[
        ,
        c(tstrsplit(subsequent_treatments, " then "), .(n = n))
    ][
        ,
        V2 := fcoalesce(V1, V2)
    ]
)
```